# Extracting multiple strings using Pythons's regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file having the following output and I have shortened it as it goes to thousands of lines:

```
Time = 1

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.230812, Final residual = 0.0134171, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.283614, Final residual = 0.0158797, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.190444, Final residual = 0.016567, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0850116, Final residual = 0.00375608, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.00999678, global = 0.00142109, cumulative = 0.00142109
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00267604, Final residual = 0.000166675, No Iterations 3
bounding omega, min: -26.6597 max: 18468.7 average: 219.43
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.0862096, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 4.84 s  ClockTime = 5 s

Time = 2

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.0299872, Final residual = 0.00230507, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.145767, Final residual = 0.00882969, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.0863129, Final residual = 0.00858536, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.394189, Final residual = 0.0175138, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.00862823, global = 0.00212477, cumulative = 0.00354587
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00258475, Final residual = 0.000222705, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.112805, Final residual = 0.0054572, No Iterations 3
ExecutionTime = 5.9 s  ClockTime = 6 s

Time = 3

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.128298, Final residual = 0.0070293, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.138825, Final residual = 0.0116437, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.0798979, Final residual = 0.00491246, No Iterations 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.108748, Final residual = 0.00429273, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.0073211, global = -0.00187909, cumulative = 0.00166678
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00238456, Final residual = 0.000224435, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.0529661, Final residual = 0.00280851, No Iterations 3
ExecutionTime = 6.92 s  ClockTime = 7 s
```

I need to extract Time = 1, 2, 3 and corresponding cumulative values using Python's regular expression. More precisely, I need to extract only the values 1, 2, 3 and 0.00142109, 0.00354587, 0.00166678 that corresponds to cumulative at Time = 1,2 and 3 and write to an another file.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
contCumulative_0_out = open('contCumulative_0', 'w+')

with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
for line in logfile_read:
    line = line.rstrip()
    iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time = ([0-9]+)', line)
    print iteration_time
    contCumulative_0 = re.search(r'cumulative = ((\d|.)+)', line)
    if contCumulative_0:        
        cumvalue = contCumulative_0.groups(1)
        contCumulative_0_out.write('\n'.join(cumvalue))
```

The variable `iteration_time` grabs the Time value, however this is not available within the next subsequent `if` loop and therefore I am unable to combine Time and cumulative to give me 1  0.00142109 in the output file.

Comment: Do the 'Time'/'time step' linesoccur only once in the logfile, or multiple times? Please update the example with those, like @Andy did.

Comment: @smci My log file goes into many thousands of lines and is identical to what Andy has put up. I will update my original post.

Comment: Yes please just post enough snippet needed for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no 'Time' or 'cumulative' in this line, there is no need to overwrite that variable. You can do this:

```
...
with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
for line in logfile_read:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if 'Time' in line:
        iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time = ([0-9]+)', line)
        print iteration_time
    if 'cumulative' in line:
        contCumulative_0 = re.search(r'cumulative = ((\d|.)+)', line)
        if contCumulative_0:
            cumvalue = contCumulative_0.groups(1)
            contCumulative_0_out.write('\n'.join(cumvalue))
...
```

Comment: Thanks every one. @m170897017 you solution worked quite well. I now have tuples and need to convert to string in order to get the right format.

Comment: Yes @m170897017 I have adopted your solution and many thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is writing over `iteration_time` in every iteration of the `for` loop. That is the problem. You will need to stop populating this variable after it has been successfully populated for the first find.

To do this, in the `for` loop do a test for `iteration_time` and only if it is non- existent or `None` do the regex search for Time. You can do soemthing like this:

```
contCumulative_0_out = open('contCumulative_0', 'w+')

with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
    iteration_time = None
    for line in logfile_read:
        line = line.rstrip()
        time_match = re.findall(r'^Time = ([0-9]+)', line)
        if time_match:
            iteration_time = time_match
            print iteration_time
        else:  # Because if there is time_match, there is no 'cumulative = ...'
            contCumulative_0 = re.search(r'cumulative = ((\d|.)+)', line)
            if contCumulative_0:        
                cumvalue = contCumulative_0.groups(1)
                # You can check and use iteration_time here
                contCumulative_0_out.write('\n'.join(cumvalue))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regex, assuming that your log format is the same for all of your entries. The explanation of what is going on is below:

```
import re

s = """Time = 1

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.230812, Final residual = 0.0134171, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.283614, Final residual = 0.0158797, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.190444, Final residual = 0.016567, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0850116, Final residual = 0.00375608, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.00999678, global = 0.00142109, cumulative = 0.00142109
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00267604, Final residual = 0.000166675, No Iterations 3
bounding omega, min: -26.6597 max: 18468.7 average: 219.43
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.0862096, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 4.84 s  ClockTime = 5 s

Time = 2

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.230812, Final residual = 0.0134171, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.283614, Final residual = 0.0158797, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.190444, Final residual = 0.016567, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0850116, Final residual = 0.00375608, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.00999678, global = 0.00142109, cumulative = 0.00123456
smoothSolver:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.00267604, Final residual = 0.000166675, No Iterations 3
bounding omega, min: -26.6597 max: 18468.7 average: 219.43
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.0862096, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 4.84 s  ClockTime = 5 s
"""

regex = re.compile("^Time = (\d+?).*?cumulative = (\d{0,10}\.\d{0,10})",re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

for x in re.findall(regex,s):
    print "{} => {}".format(x[0], x[1])
```

---

This outputs two results (because I've added two log entries, instead of just the one you provided):

```
1 => 0.00142109
2 => 0.00123456
```

---

#### What is happening?

The RegEx being utilized is this:

```
^Time = (\d+?).*?cumulative = (\d{0,10}\.\d{0,10})
```

This Regex is looking for your `Time =` string at the beginning of the line, and matching the digit that follows. Then it does a non-greedy match to the string `cumulative =` and captures the digits that follow that. The non-greedy is important, otherwise you'd only get one result in your entire log because it'd match the first instance of `Time =` and the last instance of `cumulative =`.

It then prints each result. Each captured result contains the time value and the cumulative value. This portion of the code can be modified to print to a file if required.

This regex works across multiple lines because it utilizes two flags: [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) and [MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)