# Python multiple if statements

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I am trying to grab values from a log file using Python's regular expression and in that process I have a few `if` statements. The section of the code which grabs the values is as follows:

```
# Opening the log file for reading
with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
for line in logfile_read:
    line = line.rstrip()

# To extract Time or iteration
    if 'Time' in line:
        iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)

# To extract local, global and cumulative values

    if 'local' in line:
        local_global_cumu = re.search(r'sum\s+local\s+=\s+(.*),\s+global\s+=\s+(.*),\s+cumulative\s+=\s+(.*)', line)
        if local_global_cumu:
            contLocal_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(1)
            contGlobal_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(2)
            contCumulative_0_value = local_global_cumu.group(3)
        for t in iteration_time:
            contLocal.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, contLocal_0_value))
            contGlobal.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, contGlobal_0_value))
            contCumulative.write("%s\t%s\n" %(t, contCumulative_0_value))

    # To extract execution and cpu time

    if 'ExecutionTime' in line:
        execution_cpu_time = re.search(r'^ExecutionTime\s+=\s+(.*)\s+s\s+ClockTime\s+=\s+(.*)\s+s', line)
        if execution_cpu_time:
           execution_time_0_value = execution_cpu_time.group(1)
           cpu_time_0_value = execution_cpu_time.group(2)
        for t in iteration_time:
            print t
```

In the second `if` statement, I am able to get values of `t`. However, in the subsequent `if` statement, when I try to `print t`, nothing comes. I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: If is not a loop. [And you're using if incorrectly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: I'd guess that `iteration_time` is empty, or the body of `if ('ExecutionTime' or 'ClockTime') in line:` is never executed.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwini Chaudhary. Can you give me some hints please?

Comment: `if ('ExecutionTime' or 'ClockTime') in line:` is working correctly. I tested this by printing both `execution_time_0_value` and `cpu_time_0_value` and they are successful. Thanks @Rawing

Comment: Another thing I note is, if I inset `print  iteration_time` immediately before the second `if` statement I get all the values, however if the same is done immediately after the `if` statement, I get empty list of values.

Comment: Thanks @JonClements. I have now modified my `if` statements to only look for one keyword, yet it does not print the values of `iteration_time` beyond the second `if` statement. I have also edited my original post to reflect this change.

Comment: `iteration_time` only gets set when your first `if` block runs... I'm surprised you're not getting a `NameError`... - so your `for t in iteration_time` will be r eferring to the time that last got set by your first `if`...

Comment: I am not getting any error @Jon Clements. If you look at the beginning of my code, all these `if` are getting evaluated within the `for` loop. If I not wrong, for every line it strips, the value of `t` is obtained and the same is carried for the next `if` statement. Hence, I am getting all values of `t`, except after `if 'ExecutionTime' in line:`

Comment: What I'm pointing out is that `iteration_time` has the potential to be carried across iterations of the for-loop, eg: it gets set on the first line, but never reset again, so all following iterations use whatever the last value was - that might well be desired behaviour, but we don't know that. I can't see anything wrong with your code other than that, so I'm afraid it's up to you to put some `print`s in or run it through a debugger

Comment: If `Time` is in line, but doesn't match your regex, then your result will be `[]`... however, at the point `local` is in a line and `ExecutionTime` are in a line, they may not be the same `iteration_time`, as it only gets (re)set when `Time` is in the line - in fact "ExecutionTime" - contains "Time" - so your regex will trigger, not match, return `[]`, then your "ExecutionTime" block runs with an empty `iteration_time`... that's it - your line can't both start with "Time" and "ExecutionTime" :)

Answer (score 1):

The following checks if "Time" is a substring in the line, then attempts to find all matches on that line that *begins* with "Time"...

```
if 'Time' in line:
    iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time\s+=\s+(.*)', line)
```

The following **also** contains the word "Time":

```
if 'ExecutionTime' in line:
    execution_cpu_time = re.search(r'^ExecutionTime\s+=\s+(.*)\s+s\s+ClockTime\s+=\s+(.*)\s+s', line)
```

When it attempts to loop over `iteration_time` it will be empty as the previous `if` has already run and the condition that it starts with "Time" means you get an empty list for its matches.

Let's just pretend you have a single line, starting with "ExecutionTime", and let's walk through it...

- `if 'Time' in line` is true, so the `re.findall` runs and returns all matches for the line that **starts with** 'Time'... This will be **empty** because the line **doesn't start with 'Time'** - so `iteration_time = []`
- `if 'ExecutionTime' in line` is true, and the line **does** start with 'ExecutionTime', when you do the `for t in iteration_time` - it won't loop, because the above has set it to be empty!

Comment: Thanks @Jon Clements. In my log file `Time` and `ExecutionTime` are in two different line and also the syntx for regex uses `^` which only checks for line starting with. Both my `Time` and `ExecutionTime` is at the start of two different lines.

Comment: Yes, but "Time" is in "ExecutionTime" which means that first `if` actually runs... the findall will return nothing because the line **doesn't** start with "Time" it starts with "ExecutionTime"... get it? So when the `if 'ExecutionTime'` block runs, `iteration_time` will be emptied by the first if...

Comment: Thanks @JonClements. However, I am still a bit confused. Look at my typical log file here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017121/extracting-multiple-strings-using-pythonss-regular-expression/28017210?noredirect=1#comment44422473_28017210

Comment: @Deepak it doesn't matter how your data looks, it's just logic... I've tried to spell it out with an update to the answer - if you don't get that, there's not much more I can do I'm afraid :)

Comment: @Deepak anyway - probably a quick fix is to change your line from `if 'Time' in line` to be `if line.startswith('Time')`